# var with generic enumMap declaration

Tags: java, java-10

Is this declaration

```
// version 1
EnumMap<Type, EnumSet<Part>> types = new EnumMap<>(Type.class);
```

the same as this:

```
// version 2
var types = new EnumMap<Type, EnumSet<Part>>(Type.class);
```

I think it's the same, because I can also write this:

```
EnumMap<Type, EnumSet<Part>> types = new EnumMap<Type, EnumSet<Part>(Type.class);
```

and therefore this:

```
// version 2
var types = new EnumMap<Type, EnumSet<Part>>(Type.class);
```

Are there any differences in *version 1* and *version 2*? Which should I prefer?

Comment: *"Is this declaration...the same as this..."* I'm not versed enough in Java's `var` to say for *sure*, but...what else could either of them mean? :-)

Comment: When you have to ask such questions, you should prefer variant 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, version 1 and 2 are the same.

Comment: Concise answers are great. I think you are over-doing. By far.